# How to fetch old environment variables in newer runtimes of Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

For newer runtimes of Cloud Functions, Google does not provide the same subset of [Environment Variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically) that were available for older runtimes.

Basically, newer runtimes does not provide:

- ENTRY_POINT
- GCP_PROJECT
- GCLOUD_PROJECT
- FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE
- FUNCTION_NAME
- FUNCTION_MEMORY_MB
- FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC
- FUNCTION_IDENTITY
- FUNCTION_REGION

How do I fetch this information without hardcode their values in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why Google removed these variables, but some of them can be obtained using alternative methods.

Here I list a piece of code you may want to add to your functions to get some data in a cross-compatible way (will work in both older and newer runtimes):

```python
import os
import requests     # requires: "requests"
import google.auth  # requires: "google-auth"

def query_metadata(entry):
    metadata_url = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/'
    response = requests.get(metadata_url + entry, headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'})
    return response.content.decode("utf-8")

#                   ------ Older Runtime Method ------     ------ Newer Runtime Alternative Method ------
ENTRY_POINT       = os.environ.get('ENTRY_POINT')       OR os.environ.get('FUNCTION_TARGET')
GCP_PROJECT       = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT')       OR google.auth.default()[1]
GCLOUD_PROJECT    = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT')       OR google.auth.default()[1]
FUNCTION_NAME     = os.environ.get('FUNCTION_NAME')     OR os.environ.get('K_SERVICE')
FUNCTION_IDENTITY = os.environ.get('FUNCTION_IDENTITY') OR query_metadata('instance/service-accounts/default/email')
```

If you're not using Python, you may not like the `google.auth.default()[1]` method to retrieve the project name.  Here is a second alternative to fetch this data querying the [Metadata Server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata), which I think it is easier to reproduce in other languages:

```python
import requests     # requires: "requests"

def query_metadata(entry):
    response = requests.get('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/' + entry, headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'})
    return response.content.decode("utf-8")

GCP_PROJECT = query_metadata('project/project-id')
```

I was not able to find a way to get the other environment variables (`FUNCTION_REGION`, `FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE`, `FUNCTION_MEMORY_MB` or `FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC`).  But I discuss alternatives for each one below.

### FUNCTION_REGION environment variable

This variable can't be obtained on newer runtimes.

My best current workaround is to try to extract the information from URL, but it only works with HTTP triggers.  **Use it at your own risk.**

```python
# extract region from URL using regex, expecting
# https://<region>-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>

import os
import re
import google.auth  # requires: "google-auth"

GCP_PROJECT = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT') or google.auth.default()[1]
FUNCTION_REGION = re.match(r'https?:\/\/(.*)-{}\..*'.format(GCP_PROJECT), request.url_root).group(1)
```

If this does not fit your needs, you may want to get GCP Project default region.  It works, but it **IS NOT** the same as the function region.

```python
import requests     # requires: "requests"
def query_metadata(entry):
    response = requests.get('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/' + entry, headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'})
    return response.content.decode("utf-8")

project_default_region = query_metadata('project/attributes/google-compute-default-region')
```

More precisely, you can query the zone where the function is running.  It also works, but this **IS NOT** the same as the function region (useless most of times), but it may fit someone needs.

```python
import requests     # requires: "requests"
def query_metadata(entry):
    response = requests.get('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/' + entry, headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'})
    return response.content.decode("utf-8")

function_zone = query_metadata('instance/zone')
# returns "projects/<project-id>/zones/us16"
```

You can obviously query this information from [Cloud Functions API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest).  But Cloud Functions API requires the Region as parameter (the same parameter we want to retrieve), so I think this method is useless.

As a last resort, you can use Cloud Functions API to (i) [query all supported locations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations/list); then (ii) [query all regions to list their functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/list) until you find it.  However, there are several supported regions and GCP supports functions with the same name in different regions.  So there is no guarantee this method will return only one value.

### FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE environment variable

This variable can't be obtained on newer runtimes.

Google suggests you to use `FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE` as a replacement but their domains are different.  They may serve for the same purpose, but you should be aware of this difference:

- **FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE**: `HTTP_TRIGGER`, `CLOUD_PUBSUB_TRIGGER`, `CLOUD_STORAGE_TRIGGER`, ...
- **FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE**: `http` or `event`

You can also use [Cloud Functions API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest) to get detailed information, but it is somewhat complex to write a fully cross-compatible code ([check `HttpsTrigger` and `EventTrigger` types](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudfunctions/latest/functions_v1/types.html) if you want to try).

### FUNCTION_MEMORY_MB environment variable

This variable can't be obtained on newer runtimes.

But you can query this information from [Cloud Functions API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest) if you don't mind in hardcoding your function region.

```python
import os
import google.auth                     # requires: "google-auth"
from google.cloud import functions_v1  # requires: "google-cloud-functions"

REGION        = 'us-central1'  # notice this variable is hardcoded, since there is no alternative to it

GCP_PROJECT   = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT') or google.auth.default()[1]
FUNCTION_NAME = os.environ.get('FUNCTION_NAME') or os.environ.get('K_SERVICE')

functions_client = functions_v1.services.cloud_functions_service.CloudFunctionsServiceClient()
this_function = functions_client.get_function(name='projects/{}/locations/{}/functions/{}'.format(GCP_PROJECT, REGION, FUNCTION_NAME))

FUNCTION_MEMORY_MB = this_function.available_memory_mb
```

### FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC environment variable

This variable can't be obtained on newer runtimes.

As the previous variable, you can query this information from [Cloud Functions API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest) if you don't mind in hardcoding your function region.

```python
import os
import google.auth                     # requires: "google-auth"
from google.cloud import functions_v1  # requires: "google-cloud-functions"

REGION        = 'us-central1'  # notice this variable is hardcoded, since there is no alternative to it

GCP_PROJECT   = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT') or google.auth.default()[1]
FUNCTION_NAME = os.environ.get('FUNCTION_NAME') or os.environ.get('K_SERVICE')

functions_client = functions_v1.services.cloud_functions_service.CloudFunctionsServiceClient()
this_function = functions_client.get_function(name='projects/{}/locations/{}/functions/{}'.format(GCP_PROJECT, REGION, FUNCTION_NAME))

FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC = this_function.timeout
```